# How to build index and query with time range and id sort?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Here is the table data

| id | time | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20221104 | 15 |
| 2 | 20221104 | 10 |
| 3 | 20221105 | 7 |
| 4 | 20221105 | 19 |
| 5 | 20221106 | 10 |

The id and time field is asc, but time can be same.

The rows are very large, so we don't want to use page limit offset method, but with cursor id.

first query:

`select * from t where time > xxx and time < yyy order by id asc limit 10;`

get the biggest id zzz, then

next query:

`select * from t where time > xxx and time < yyy and id > zzz order by id asc limit 10;`

How should I build the index?
If I use id as index, the time range will cause huge scan if time is far away.
And If I use time as index, seek id will not be effective.

Comment: Is `Id` and `time` both increasing? Then how about `select id from t where time < yyy order by id desc limit 1;`  A simple index on time (desc) could handle that for you

Comment: @mikkel the same time can contain mutiple id

Comment: Yes, but the first Id will be at the date closest to xxx and the last Id at the date closest to yyy. So no need to scan the index range. Just index by time, Id and get the first (or last) entry

Answer (score 0):

The following index should be enough for both queries:

```
alter table t add index `time_id` (`time`,`id`);
```

*Note*, use proper date/datetime data types , will save a lot of pain in the future

Comment: The query should be "select * from t where time < yyy and time >= newxxx and id > newzzz order by time asc, id asc"?

Comment: @JimmyGuo would cover that as well, add the following index and test with execution plan

Answer (score 0):

The key is composite index by leftmost prefixing principle. But both queries here start with
range expression. So I suppose that simply creating index on `(a, b)` is unable to optimize effectively
because indexing process stops after range condition. It is enough to create index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_time ON t (`time`)
```

More can be referenced here:

- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=indexes-use-composite
- https://orangematter.solarwinds.com/2019/02/05/the-left-prefix-index-rule/

Answer (score 0):

First I agree with @ErgestBasha Suggestion:

If you follow the general performance rules:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT, time DATE, amount DEC(3,1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES
    -> (1, '2022-11-04', 15),
    -> (2, '2022-11-04', 10),
    -> (3, '2022-11-05', 7),
    -> (4, '2022-11-05', 19),
    -> (5, '2022-11-06', 10);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
+------+------------+--------+
| id   | time       | amount |
+------+------------+--------+
|    1 | 2022-11-04 |   15.0 |
|    2 | 2022-11-04 |   10.0 |
|    3 | 2022-11-05 |    7.0 |
|    4 | 2022-11-05 |   19.0 |
|    5 | 2022-11-06 |   10.0 |
+------+------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE t ADD INDEX idx_time_id (time,id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM t;
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| t     |          1 | idx_time_id |            1 | time        | A         |           3 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| t     |          1 | idx_time_id |            2 | id          | A         |           5 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t WHERE time > '2022-11-04' AND time < '2022-11-06' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;
+------+------------+--------+
| id   | time       | amount |
+------+------------+--------+
|    4 | 2022-11-05 |   19.0 |
+------+------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t WHERE time > '2022-11-04' AND time < '2022-11-06' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | range | idx_time_id   | idx_time_id | 4       | NULL |    2 |    33.33 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, It uses the indexes defined (time,id) and uses the range scan access method. Also Extra column you can see that index is used during operation!

Answer (score 0):

See this for iterating through a compound key:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#iterating_through_a_compound_key
It cannot be done with two `ANDs`; tt needs one `AND` and one `OR`.

See this for why `OFFSET` should be avoided when [*Paginating*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)